# How do I send data to a php file from my installer?

Tags: php, nsis

I am trying to verify user passwords on my NSIS installer so I am sending to my encoding php script to compare values. It does not seem to be interacting with the php script at all. I believe my issue might be in the PHP.

```
<?php
include ("Encryption.php");
$data = $_POST;
$a = new encryption_class();
$encryption = //encryption code;
?>

<html><head>

<title> - </title></head>
<body>
    <? echo $data ?> <br>
    <? echo $encryption;?>

</body>
</html>
```

I feel like i am missing something when i try to send the information from the installer to the php script with the post method.

Sorry...here is the NSIS call

```
    Section
    SetOutPath $DOCUMENTS/
    StrCpy $1 "userpass"
    #text files for reading and writing with the post command
    File "pass.txt"
    File "encrypt.txt"

    #write the user variable to the pass.txt file
    ClearErrors
    FileOpen $0 pass.txt w
    IfErrors done
    FileWrite $0 "$1"
    FileClose $0
done:
    FileOpen $3 encrypt.txt w
    inetc::post $0 /FILE "http://mywebserver/installer_get_pass.php" $3 /END

SectionEnd
```

I haven't finished the script but when i open the txt file where the output should be written it is blank

Comment: Show us what's in `$_POST`.  Show us how you're doing your post from your NSIS script.  Your question is completely unanswerable without some of this basic information.

Comment: `$_POST` is an array. Echoing it would just print `array` or if error reporting is enabled and configured to show notices you will get `Notice: Array to string conversion`. You need to iterate over the array and print whatever you need

Comment: Use `var_dump` to actually see what's in `$_POST`. You will probably also want to inspect `$_FILES`.

Comment: i did a var_dump on the $_POST array and its coming up empty so it doesn't look like the NSIS is sending anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inetc::post $0` passes a (closed!) file handle to the plugin. Parameter `$3` a similar problem, try using paths:

```
...
done:
StrCpy $0 "$documens\pass.txt"
StrCpy $3 "$documens\encoded.txt"
inetc::post $0 /FILE "http://mywebserver/installer_get_pass.php" $3 /END
```

Comment: thanks that helped. As far as the nsis goes its now receiving data from the php file. Unfortunately the php file is not getting the data and setting it in the $_POST array.

Comment: Maybe you have to put the /FILE switch before $0, or maybe try without /FILE and just use a normal string first...

Comment: I tried but it made it not print anything to the text file. Is it possible that I am missing a command in the php to receive the post data from a program?

Comment: inetc::post "user=foo&pass=bar" "http://posttestserver.com/post.php" "$temp\test.txt" /END seems to work, not sure what the server has to support when using /FILE though.

Comment: the "user=foo&pass=bar" part of that statement, thats not coming from a text file is it?

Comment: No, but if you don't have a large amount of data you don't really need to use a file...